# Linux command to define ad hoc option/switch overloading in utils

Tags: linux, command-line

Suppose some favorite util `foo` has a useful switch `-n bar` which is almost but not quite what's needed.  To get what's needed, one could:

- Edit the source code to add what's needed.  (Usually not portable, unless an upstream author likes the edit.)
- Make a shell wrapper script or function to add what's needed -- but unless the syntax of `foo` is very simple, parsing a new or extended switch can be difficult.  Not because the function is difficult, but because the parsing might be.

Is there some tool that works like an alias or wrapper function for single switches of utils?  Something that would work like:

```
myfunction() { new code goes here... }
wrap '-n=myfunction bar' foo ... -n 3 ...
```

Or if the `-n` switch will see a lot of use:

```
myfunction() { new code goes here... }
foo() { wrap '-n=myfunction bar' foo ... -n 3 ... ; }
```

Or suppose `-n bar` only allows *bar* to be an integer, and we need a little tweak to handle a floating point number, but needn't replace `-n` *unless* it's floating point:

```
wrap '-n=myfunction bar==fp_only` foo ... -n 3.2 ...
```

Another use for a `wrap` might be to temporarily handle an unfixed bug:

```
wrap '-n=myfunction bar==x' foo ... -n x ...
```

...where `x` is some value, (or set of values), sure to cause trouble without some judicious pre-parsing and reformatting.

Another use would be to *add* a switch where none exists, (provided it's made up of existing switch functions, or only effects output):

```
newswitchcode() { ...code... }
wrap '-p=newswitchcode bar'   foo ... -p 3 ...
```

Note that a `wrap` would only be feasible for utils with simple output.  Utils with complex internal data pipelines like `find` wouldn't be be a good fit.

Comment: I think the normal way to do this would be to simply write the shell wrapper, as you describe in your second bullet. In fact, I'm not sure I see any difference between that and what you want. All your shell wrapper would have to do is deal with your exception cases, then just call the original with the adjusted parameters and flags.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, Really the *only* difference is convenience, but many utils are like that.  Instead of firing up an external editor, it'd just be the CLI line-editor for quick hacks.  The `wrap` util would include some automatic prefab type checking or simple data conversion, (suppose the target util only understands decimal input, but hex would be simper, *etc*...), which would be more of a pain to do on-the-fly.

Comment: The thing is, each 'wrappable' command will have different needs; what you eventually write to tell your hypothetical `wrap` what to do with a particular command wouldn't actually be any less complex than writing a wrapping script with ed, vi, emacs, etc.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, Think of it like `xargs` -- `xargs` does nothing a data feeder wrapper script couldn't do, but `xargs`, despite internally being more complex than a wrapper script, is often more convenient to use than writing such a script would be.  Helper utils like `xargs` are **not** universal fixes -- they help sometimes, and it's up to users to decide when.

Comment: `xargs` is a serious hack, and really should be abolished - it breaks the philosophy of *ix utils; it does too much. What it _should_ do is simply convert stdin into a parameter for a util that wasn't written to read from stdin - anything else is hackery that should have been handled with other utils like `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, and so on, possibly with additional invocations of the 'simple `xargs`' as needed. [More...]

Comment: [...eroM] Even if you allow `xargs` philosophically, its processing is purely textual; you seem to want more, such as conversion of floats into ints - and what's the right way to do that? Or arbitrary preprocessing of args - which you can do with the stock shell script as above (which may include using `xargs`), or possibly with PowerShell.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, Perhaps you're right, but since I like `xargs`, you're in effect moralizing to a software pervert.  If we don't know of an *existing* util that fits the bill, software tools philosophy, however worthwhile, seems somewhat off topic...

Comment: You miss the point - _what `xargs` does is strictly textual manipulation_. What you appear to want is _intelligent_ reparsing _by_ your utility, or for your utility to call a function that you define. In the former case, where does the intelligence come from - i.e., how does your utility know which of several cases to apply to a particular class of reparse - and in the latter case, you're writing the function anyway, so just go the extra step, and save it to a shell script (which means you won't have to reconstruct it the next time you need it).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, `xargs` was noted as an example of a complex util that saves the trouble of writing a script; it's specific workings being irrelevant to this Q.   Re "*...which of several cases...*":  I'm confused... which cases?

Comment: You used as an example the desire to pass a float to a util that only takes an int: how do you convert your float to an int meaningfully? Round down? Round up? Truncate? Lookup table? Some sort of user-defined complex (as in complicated, not as in having an imaginary component) function? You're going to have to define the conversion on a case-by-case basis - and that's the core of what the shell wrapper would do, so what are you _actually_ saving?

Comment: If what you want in a particular case is purely textual beyond what `xargs` can handle, your shell wrapper would include a pipe of `sed` or `awk` plus possibly `xargs`; for non-textual, you'd have to write an individual wrap function for each utility, so what's the point in passing a function that you already have to write to an `xargs`-like preprocessor?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, Note the words "*we need a little tweak*" in the OP.  Since it's an example of syntax, It doesn't matter what the tweak is, or the nature of the program.  Please suppose that the target program actually *can* handle *fp*, but the programmer neglected to implement that handling in one of the switches, and several little kludges exist.

Comment: You still have to apply the various 'tweaks' on a case-by-case basis. _Where is the saving?_

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, As noted before, the saving is not writing a script, and whatever other functions and features a `wrap` util can usefully abstract.

Comment: What is the difference between writing the function that you would pass to *`wrap` and writing a shell wrapper to implement the function and pass it to whatever *`wrap` would pass it to? I truly do not see any saving there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75535/discussion-between-agc-and-jeff-zeitlin).

Comment: Once I go back to work - I'm on vacation this week - chat isn't realistically accessible to me; I'm normally sleeping at these weird hours when I'm accessing from home this week.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly one of these (from a longer list) may help. Not simple, however.

```
3) getopt, enhanced getopts, part of the util-linux, allows GNU "--"
   Examples: /usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples, 2016.03.27

4) argp.sh, wrapper for getopt, creates man and help (text, XML), etc.
   Allows mixed options and arguments.
   Compiled argp.c -> argp for faster execution.
   https://sourceforge.net/projects/argpsh/, 2016.03.27

5) shflags, wrapper for getopt, creates help, allow mixed options
   and arguments
   https://github.com/kward/shflags, 2016.08.01
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Comment: Those are all useful for writing versatile wrapper scripts, but it's not clear how they help with this question, which is about a util to *avoid* writing wrapper scripts.